error: unknown type name ‘max_align_t’ when building GCC 14.2 for centos7
I am building gcc 14.2.0 from source for centos7 and ran into the following issue with gettext during the make process. I plan to use the recent C++ compilers that comes with gcc 14.
gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\"\" -I. -I../../../gcc-14.2.0/gettext/gettext-runtime/gnulib-lib -I..  -I../intl -I../../../gcc-14.2.0/gettext/gettext-runtime/intl -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1   -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-conversion -Wno-float-equal -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-undef -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-pedantic -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-type-limits -Wno-unsuffixed-float-constants -g -c -o unistr/libgrt_a-u8-uctomb.o `test -f 'unistr/u8-uctomb.c' || echo '../../../gcc-14.2.0/gettext/gettext-runtime/gnulib-lib/'`unistr/u8-uctomb.c
In file included from ../../../gcc-14.2.0/gettext/gettext-runtime/gnulib-lib/scratch_buffer.h:115:0,
                 from ../../../gcc-14.2.0/gettext/gettext-runtime/gnulib-lib/malloc/scratch_buffer_grow.c:23:
./malloc/scratch_buffer.gl.h:70:9: error: unknown type name ‘max_align_t’
   union { max_align_t __align; char __c[1024]; } __space;
         ^

My gettext vesion is
# gettext --version
gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.22
Copyright (C) 1995-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.

This is how I tried to build it
yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
yum install -y wget bzip2 tar

GCC_VERSION=14.2.0
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-$GCC_VERSION/gcc-$GCC_VERSION.tar.gz
tar -xvzf gcc-$GCC_VERSION.tar.gz
cd gcc-$GCC_VERSION

./contrib/download_prerequisites
mkdir ../gcc-build
cd ../gcc-build
../gcc-$GCC_VERSION/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib

make -j$(nproc)
make install

Could someone kindly help me out to install gcc 14? Is there any way to solve this issue?

I'm not able to add comment yet, so I write reply here instead. Sorry for the inconvenience.
This GCC Bugzilla bug report matches your question. In brief, Arsen Arsenović made a patch to work around it and proved it's working. You can find the patch at GCC Bugzilla or at sourceware mailing list.
The patch content:
From 55ec0a5e7c49170a18434dccfec7107626ff613d Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: =?UTF-8?q?Arsen=20Arsenovi=C4=87?= <arsen@aarsen.me>
Date: Wed, 20 Dec 2023 17:05:55 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] toplevel: don't override gettext-runtime/configure-discovered
 build args

ChangeLog:
    PR bootstrap/112534
    * Makefile.def (host-gettext): Set all_args_override="".
    * Makefile.in: Regenerate.
    * Makefile.tpl (all--args): Define as a helper macro for
    computing extra arguments to make.
    (all): Use all--args over args.
---
 Makefile.def |  2 ++
 Makefile.in  | 40 +++++++++++++++++++++-------------------
 Makefile.tpl |  8 +++++---
 3 files changed, 28 insertions(+), 22 deletions(-)

diff --git a/Makefile.def b/Makefile.def
index 3f8962c28032..93222bfd7a4b 100644
--- a/Makefile.def
+++ b/Makefile.def
@@ -76,6 +76,8 @@ host_modules= { module= gprof; };
 host_modules= { module= gprofng; };
 host_modules= { module= gettext; bootstrap=true; no_install=true;
                 module_srcdir= "gettext/gettext-runtime";
+       // Don't override configure-discovered build arguments
+       all_args_override="";
        // We always build gettext with pic, because some packages (e.g. gdbserver)
        // need it in some configuratons, which is determined via nontrivial tests.
        // Always enabling pic seems to make sense for something tied to
diff --git a/Makefile.in b/Makefile.in
index c6313048c914..e67a50750c76 100644
--- a/Makefile.in
+++ b/Makefile.in
@@ -3168,6 +3168,8 @@ TAGS: do-TAGS
 
 
 
+
+
 # --------------------------------------
 # Modules which run on the build machine
 # --------------------------------------
@@ -20189,7 +20191,7 @@ all-gettext: configure-gettext
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    $(HOST_EXPORTS)  \
    (cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-     $(MAKE) $(BASE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(STAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+     $(MAKE) $(BASE_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  $(STAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        $(TARGET-gettext))
 @endif gettext
 
@@ -20219,7 +20221,7 @@ all-stage1-gettext: configure-stage1-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS)  \
+         \
        $(STAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGE1_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stage1-gettext)
@@ -20234,7 +20236,7 @@ clean-stage1-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stage1-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS)  \
+   $(MAKE)   \
    $(STAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
@@ -20264,7 +20266,7 @@ all-stage2-gettext: configure-stage2-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGE2_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stage2-gettext)
 
@@ -20278,7 +20280,7 @@ clean-stage2-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stage2-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
@@ -20307,7 +20309,7 @@ all-stage3-gettext: configure-stage3-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGE3_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stage3-gettext)
 
@@ -20321,7 +20323,7 @@ clean-stage3-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stage3-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
@@ -20350,7 +20352,7 @@ all-stage4-gettext: configure-stage4-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGE4_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stage4-gettext)
 
@@ -20364,7 +20366,7 @@ clean-stage4-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stage4-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
@@ -20393,7 +20395,7 @@ all-stageprofile-gettext: configure-stageprofile-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGEprofile_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stageprofile-gettext)
 
@@ -20407,7 +20409,7 @@ clean-stageprofile-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stageprofile-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
@@ -20436,7 +20438,7 @@ all-stagetrain-gettext: configure-stagetrain-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGEtrain_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stagetrain-gettext)
 
@@ -20450,7 +20452,7 @@ clean-stagetrain-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stagetrain-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
@@ -20479,7 +20481,7 @@ all-stagefeedback-gettext: configure-stagefeedback-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGEfeedback_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stagefeedback-gettext)
 
@@ -20493,7 +20495,7 @@ clean-stagefeedback-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stagefeedback-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
@@ -20522,7 +20524,7 @@ all-stageautoprofile-gettext: configure-stageautoprofile-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGEautoprofile_TFLAGS)"  \
        $(TARGET-stageautoprofile-gettext)
 
@@ -20536,7 +20538,7 @@ clean-stageautoprofile-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stageautoprofile-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
@@ -20565,7 +20567,7 @@ all-stageautofeedback-gettext: configure-stageautofeedback-gettext
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
+        $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGEautofeedback_TFLAGS)" PERF_DATA=perf.data \
        $(TARGET-stageautofeedback-gettext)
 
@@ -20579,7 +20581,7 @@ clean-stageautofeedback-gettext:
      $(MAKE) stageautofeedback-start; \
    fi; \
    cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/gettext && \
-   $(MAKE) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
+   $(MAKE)  $(POSTSTAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  clean
 @endif gettext-bootstrap
 
 
diff --git a/Makefile.tpl b/Makefile.tpl
index 6e22adecd2f1..2c9226af74da 100644
--- a/Makefile.tpl
+++ b/Makefile.tpl
@@ -1258,6 +1258,8 @@ configure-stage[+id+]-[+prefix+][+module+]:
 [+ ENDIF bootstrap +]
 [+ ENDDEF +]
 
+[+ DEFINE all--args +][+ (get "all_args_override" (get "args")) +][+ ENDDEF +]
+
 [+ DEFINE all +]
 .PHONY: all-[+prefix+][+module+] maybe-all-[+prefix+][+module+]
 maybe-all-[+prefix+][+module+]:
@@ -1274,7 +1276,7 @@ all-[+prefix+][+module+]: configure-[+prefix+][+module+][+ IF bootstrap +][+ ELS
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    [+exports+] [+extra_exports+] \
    (cd [+subdir+]/[+module+] && \
-     $(MAKE) $(BASE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) [+args+] [+stage1_args+] [+extra_make_flags+] \
+     $(MAKE) $(BASE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) [+all--args+] [+stage1_args+] [+extra_make_flags+] \
        $(TARGET-[+prefix+][+module+]))
 @endif [+prefix+][+module+]
 
@@ -1309,7 +1311,7 @@ all-stage[+id+]-[+prefix+][+module+]: configure-stage[+id+]-[+prefix+][+module+]
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
        LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)" \
-       [+args+] [+IF prev +][+poststage1_args+][+ ELSE prev +] \
+       [+all--args+] [+IF prev +][+poststage1_args+][+ ELSE prev +] \
        [+stage1_args+][+ ENDIF prev +] [+extra_make_flags+] \
        TFLAGS="$(STAGE[+id+]_TFLAGS)" [+profile_data+] \
        $(TARGET-stage[+id+]-[+prefix+][+module+])
@@ -1324,7 +1326,7 @@ clean-stage[+id+]-[+prefix+][+module+]:
      $(MAKE) stage[+id+]-start; \
    fi; \
    cd [+subdir+]/[+module+] && \
-   $(MAKE) [+args+] [+ IF prev +][+poststage1_args+][+ ELSE prev +] \
+   $(MAKE) [+all--args+] [+ IF prev +][+poststage1_args+][+ ELSE prev +] \
    [+stage1_args+][+ ENDIF prev +] [+extra_make_flags+] clean
 @endif [+prefix+][+module+]-bootstrap
 
-- 
2.43.0

